# Populate slideshow with images from a folder

Tags: php, html, slideshow

I want to get all the images that exist in the folder and display them in my slideshow.

This is the error I see on the console:

```
localhost/:74 GET http://localhost/%22$img/%22 403 (Forbidden)
```

This is my html file:

```
  <div class="slider">



    <ul>
      <?php
      $images = Glob("Presentacion/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
      foreach($images as $img) {
      <li> <img src=\"$img\"  alt=""> </li>
    }
      ?>



    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: 74 is the  line form  error and label <img>

Answer (score 0):

Only strings in quotes are interpreted by PHP. Haven't tried it, but this should work.

```
  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <?php
          $images = glob("Presentacion/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
          foreach($images as $img) {
             echo "<li> <img src=\"$img\" alt=\"\"> </li>";
          }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

For more informations on strings see the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php)

Comment: in the html document I see this when update the page ":}?>  I don't not what happen  :c

Comment: Are you sure your quotes are exactly as shown above? Just tested it on my local dev server and it works as expected.

Comment: They are all exactly the same

Comment: Consider using an IDE like PHPStorm. It shows you errors it spots, directly in the code. Eliminating most of the guess work.